# Is it safe to hot-plug a DVI cable?

Tags: display, dvi, hotplug

Is it safe to unplug a monitor connected via a DVI cable to a computer that's powered on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply, yes. The DVI spec is engineered for the Universal Plug and Play.
http://www.ddwg.org/lib/dvi_10.pdf

Comment: So that time when I unplugged the DVI cable going to my TV from the second output on my video card, and my PC instantly rebooted, means that either the cable doesn't meet spec or there's something wrong with my video card, right?

Comment: @DanHenderson either the video card, driver or OS, yes. I guess there's all sorts of hardware issues could cause something like that...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. the digital visual interface (DVI) is hot pluggable. The pin 16 specifies hot plug detection.