# when attaching external display to laptop should I turn it off?

Tags: external-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to hot-plug a DVI cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/222205/is-it-safe-to-hot-plug-a-dvi-cable)

I was just wondering, and couldn't find relevant documentation, when attaching external display to (macbook air in my case, but should be same for all laptops?) laptop via DVI or VGA should computer be turned off? and turn on once monitor is attached? or is it safe to hotplug it when laptop is running?

if hotplug is ok, should I have ext monitor turned off, and turn it on once plug is in?

any thoughts on this?

or am I just thinking to much about these things? :)

Comment: Just don't bother its all depend on you how you want to do it? You can keep the display on while attach to external monitor its not harmful in any way.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Is VGA port hot-pluggable?](http://superuser.com/questions/112309/is-vga-port-hot-pluggable) and [Is it safe to hot-plug a DVI cable?](http://superuser.com/questions/222205/is-it-safe-to-hot-plug-a-dvi-cable) and from earlier today (just because ;) ): [Is HDMI hot pluggable?](http://superuser.com/questions/440959/is-hdmi-hot-pluggable)

Comment: :) yes I have noticed those in the sidebar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can safely plug in or plug out external display while both laptop and display are turned on.